# Mysql consulta intervalos

Tags: mysql, sql

Preciso montar um select, onde preciso exibir os resultados fora de um intervalo de código. Por exemplo: tenho o código 2 como inicio e o código 6 como fim, como poderia fazer para não exibir os códigos 3, 4  e 5  e exibir somente o código 1 e do 5 em diante? Somente com SQL é possivel?

Com esse select consigo não exibir o codigo inicial e final, mas continua mostrando o que tem entre eles

```
SELECT h.cod, h.horario FROM horarios h 
WHERE h.cod NOT IN (SELECT cod_hora_saida FROM reservas) AND 
      h.cod NOT IN (SELECT cod_hora_prevista FROM reservas) 
ORDER BY h.cod ASC
```

UPDATE

Sigo tentando, mas não consegui ainda mostrar o resultado que preciso. As tabelas que uso são as 2 abaixo
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O resultado que estou tentando é esse, usando as tabelas abaixo como exemplo:

06:00
06:30
07:00
07:30
08:00
08:30
09:00
09:30
10:00
13:00
13:30
14:00
14:30
15:00
18:00
18:30
19:00

ULTIMO UPDATE

Testei a função union all, com uma reserva deu certo, mas se tiver mais de uma no mesmo dia já não funciona. Sugestões?

```html
select * from horarios where cod < 20 union all select * from horarios where cod > 25
```

Comment: O que você já tentou fazer?

Comment: Ja tentou SELECT * FROM tabela where codigo >= 1 and codigo <  2 and codigo >= 5?

Comment: Sim, ele continua mostrando

Comment: editei a pergunta com as ultimas tentativas que fiz.

Comment: Na sua primeira query tire o `AND`  e coloque um `OR`. Poste o resultado!!!

Comment: Não, trouxe como resultado a tabela inteira de horários...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se alguém passar por um problema parecido, a solução foi essa:

```
SELECT * FROM HORARIO H
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT * FROM RESERVA R
 WHERE H.COD BETWEEN R.SAIDA AND R.RETORNO-1)
ORDER BY H.COD
```

Obrigado